# Show a form or another after clicking a button

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have two different forms, `modulo-1` and `modulo-2`. 1 is for booking and 2 is for cancelling a reservation. I need that the correct form is showing only after clicking the relative button.

I've managed to hide the form I don't need after clicking the button, but my problem is that when I open the page the forms are both visible. How can I solve this?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var bottone = jQuery('[class^="bottone"]');
  bottone.click(function() {
    bottone.removeClass('active')
    jQuery(this).addClass('active')
    var numero = jQuery(this).data('numero')
    jQuery('.modulo-' + numero).fadeIn().siblings('[class^="modulo"]').fadeOut()
```

Comment: Use CSS. Assuming the second form should be hidden by default: `.modulo-2 { display: none; }`

Comment: jQuery('.modulo-' + numero).show()  / jQuery('.modulo-' + numero).hide()